# JSDoc - proper way to create custom type in a separated file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I want to create custom type in order to for example code completion, in separated file named `custom-types.js`, in way I found in [Rzslider angular repository](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider), in file [Rzslider.js file](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/blob/master/rzslider.js) at the bottom:

```
/**
 *
 * @name Author
 * @property {number} id
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {string} surname
 */
```

Is this the proper way to document own types? It's important that it should be in separated file, to pollute code as little as possible with `JSDoc` comments. I am using `JSDoc 3` with plugin bounded to Intellij 14, thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: About documenting angular codes with jsdoc, I have answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24208836/2197555).

Comment: @gm2008 Thanks, could you place your answer as regular post? Then I can accept it.

Comment: About documenting angular codes with jsdoc, I have answered a similar question. Please refer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24208836/2197555).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment.